# I cannot delete a scratch org by running sfdx force:org:delete cmd

Tags: salesforcedx

I cannot run the sfdx force:org:delete cmd to delete a scratch org.

```
$ sfdx force:org:delete -u scratchOrgAlias -p 
ERROR running force:org:delete:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getOrgId')
```

This is my sfdx version and sf version

```
$ sfdx -v
sfdx-cli/7.129.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.13.0
```

```
$ sf -v
@salesforce/cli/1.4.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.13.0
```

Did anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

First confirm if you have an org with a proper alias name.

You can do this by `sfdx alias:list`, check if you have that alias name listed in the output of this command.

Later you can delete this via same command which you mentioned .

`sfdx force:org:delete -p -u 'YOUR_ORG_ALIAS_NAME'`

Comment: My org alias is correct. For deleting a scratch org, it needs to add -v devHubOrgAlias as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest sfdx cli needs to specify the DevHubOrg when doing the scratch org deletion.

```
$ sfdx force:org:delete -u scratchOrgAlias -v devHubOrgAlias -p
```

Answer (score 0):

There was [an issue in specific versions of SFDX CLI](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1423). To fix this issue, you need to upgrade to SFDX CLI version 7.145.0

Also there might be problems if devhub is authorized after the scratch org.